# Rails can't execute rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rake

Rails won't fire off a rake command from my controller because it can't find rake. I know this because I experienced this in my dev environment and fixed it by giving it the absolute path to rake. However this solution isn't working my production environment.

Things I know:

1. I can run the rake task rom cli
2. I can run it through irb with a: system "rake ..."
3. I can't find any errors!

Rakes:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake
/usr/bin/rake
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake
/var/lib/gems/1.8/doc/rake-0.9.2.2/rdoc/lib/rake
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.3.1/lib/rake
```

How in the heck do I go about troubleshooting this???

Comment: Why are you trying to invoke a `rake` task from within your controller? That is a very atypical thing for a Rails app to be doing.

Comment: Could you add the code of the use case, where you use rake inside of a controller...

Comment: Hey Meager, I know it's not the blessed way but it makes sense in my scenario. The problem I'm trying to solve and understand here is why I can't call my rake task from rails in my production environment. I'm using --> system "#{SITE_rake_path} #{task} #{args.join(' ')} >> #{Rails.root}/log/rake.log &". Works in my dev once I got the right rake path. But unfortunately not in production (dev = lucid32, prod = debian)

Comment: This translates to --> system "rake invite INVITE_ID=5 RAILS_ENV=production >> /root/log/rake.log &". Could it be my log?

Comment: explain the non-technical problem you are trying to solve without using the words rake, rails or environment.  When I do structure my questions more that way I am often humbly surprised.

Comment: if I remove the trailing "&" it works. I forgot to add that...however, I need that to run the command in the background. ugh...

Comment: ok I think I figured it out...posting synopsis in a minute..

Answer (score 0):

The rake task I was calling in production was failing because of my attempt to dump it's contents into a log with logger disabled.

```
system "rake invite INVITE_ID=5 RAILS_ENV=production >> /root/log/rake.log &"
```

Thanks for all your help...sorry for being so vague. I was just looking for quick responses hoping I was doing something stupid. Which I was. I SWEAR I tried it without the log entry...probably moving too fast like I always do.

Also, just to answer a couple questions. The rake task I'm using is an internal tool I use myself for some maintenance and want to simply offload that task to my coworker who uses an app I've built. There's no need to industrialize it with a scheduler, etc...

Comment: What method did you use to execute the rake command from the controller? I'm trying to do something similar with a gem other than rake? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011404/call-a-rubygems-binary-executable-from-inside-my-rails-applications