# Call a rubygem's binary executable from inside my rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I know that bundler makes a gems executables available using the `bundle exec` command. I want to understand how I can call these executables from inside a controller action or model class method? I don't see anything about this in the Bundler doco.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your issue ?

Comment: I think I want to use the Kernel system! method. to execute commands, but I like the answer given by Jef, that might be the solution.

Comment: Another Option seems to be the IO.popen() method.

Comment: There are several ways to execute shell commands in Ruby: `Kernel#exec`, `Kernel#system`, backticks, `IO#popen`, `Open3#popen3`, `Open4#popen4`. If the commands you want to execute sit in gems it sounds weird to perform a system call from a ruby app to execute ruby code, you'd rather use the gems API.

Answer (score 0):

Executables are ruby scripts sitting in the `bin` directory of the gems and their behavior depend on each gem. They are wrappers around the gems classes/APIs: simply dig into the source code of the gems you target and mimic the behavior of their CLIs.